# RHEL 8 mdadm assembly: "No recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb, /dev/sdb has no superblock - aborting"

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have a few different external drives that I would like to be interchangeable (not necessarily in content but in terms of how the system addresses them). When any of them are connected they appear as `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`, and these are then mounted as a RAID1 array (I have them encrypted as well but that's a later step). What I am trying to do is no matter which one of my external drives are connected, it will assemble as `/dev/md127`. What I am seeing is that only the most-recently formatted drive is able to be assembled by `mdadm --assemble --scan` and the others return the following errors:

`mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb`

`mdadm: /dev/sdb has no superblock - assembly aborted`

`mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically`

I am creating the RAID1 on these drives with the following command:

`mdadm --create /dev/md127 --force --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc`

And since I want to manually "unlock" these drives (I don't want them to assemble on boot), the only line in /etc/mdadm.conf is:

`AUTO -all`

I have seen others say that running the RAID creation line again will ask if I would like to continue creating the array, and answering "yes" will simply assemble it like I am expecting. I am weary of trying this and that not being the case, however, so I am wondering if there is a better way to handle the identical formatting of these drives? Thank you in advance!

Comment: if there is a partition table on it, then something simply wipes your mdadm header by creating one for you. (this is why you should use partitions in the first place)